# unsure how to forceupdate() react native for rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I read its bad practice to use forceUpdate, however the data that i am pushing gets stored in a separate array js folder. I have read about passing a function to the child screen and before you do a goBack ( I am using React Navigation ) call that function.

I am still new to React, so what little explainations about the two I could not understand. I have also provided a sample of the json data array that is storing all of the stuff.

So what I am trying to do is 

 Screen1 -> Screen2(form)data pushed to none state array -> Rerender Screen1

Update:
I have just thought about passing userData: userDate into the parent state, however I am unsure how to push the new form data into the array and also update the state if so

```js
export var userData= [
  {
    'title': 'First Program',
    'description': 'This is the description for the first program',
    'workoutName':[
      {
        'workoutTitle': 'First Workout',
        'workoutDescription': 'This is empty',
        'exerciseList': []
      },
    ]
  }
 ]
```

.

This is the first screen------------------

```js
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../../styling/style.js';
import { Text, View, Image, TouchableHighlight, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
// -------------------------------------------------
import { userData } from '../../config/data';
import Forms from '../FormPage';


export default class ProgramLists extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
      // These inputs will be used to link to program/workout/exercise titles and descriptions
      userData: userData
  };
}    
render() {
  // this.props.navigation.navigate is shorthanded into this below.
  // Be aware there are multiple NavigationActions that use this.props.navigation, so my not be used in all cases.
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  return (    
    <Image style={styles.workoutContainer, { flex: 1}} source={require("../../images/HomepageBackground.jpg")}>
    <View style={styles.workoutScrollView}>  
     <ScrollView>
        <List style={styles.listBody}>
          {this.state.userData.map((data, i) => (
            <ListItem titleStyle={{color: 'white'}} subtitleStyle={{color: 'black', fontSize: 12}} 
              key={i}
              title={`${data.title.toUpperCase()}`}
              subtitle={data.description}
              onPress={() => navigate('WorkoutList', {...data})}
            />
          ))}
        </List>
      </ScrollView>
      </View>
        <View style={styles.createButton}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigate('Form', {titlePassed: 'program'})} style={styles.addButtonTouch}>
         <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>+</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    </Image>    
    );
  }

// End of the render
}
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../styling/style.js';
import { Text, View, Image, TouchableHighlight, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'
// -------------------------------------------------
import { userData, specificExercises } from '../config/data';


export default class Forms extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
      // These inputs will be used to link to program/workout/exercise titles and descriptions
      InputTitle: '',
      InputDescription: '',
  };
}    
render() {
  return (    
    <Image style={styles.workoutContainer, { flex: 1}} source={require("../images/HomepageBackground.jpg")}>
      <View style={styles.workoutBody}>
        <Text style={styles.formHeader}><Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Add a new </Text>{this.Textone()} </Text>
          <TextInput
            ref="input1"
            autoCorrect={false} 
            style={styles.formBody}
            onChangeText={(InputTitle) => this.setState({InputTitle})}
            placeholder='Title'
            value={this.state.InputTitle} />
        <Text style={styles.formHeader}><Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Description</Text> {this.Texttwo()}</Text>
          <TextInput
            ref="input2"
            autoCorrect={false} 
            style={styles.formBody}
            placeholder='Description'
            onChangeText={(InputDescription) => this.setState({InputDescription})}
            value={this.state.InputDescription} />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.Addprogram(this.state.InputTitle, this.state.InputDescription)} style={styles.buttonBody} title="Add Program" >
          <Text>Add Program</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>  
      </View>
      <View>
      </View>
    </Image>    
    );
  }

Addprogram = (title, description) => {
  switch (this.props.navigation.state.params.titlePassed) {
    case 'program':
      userData.push({ 'title': title,
                      'description': description,
                      'workoutName':[]
                    });
      break;
    case 'workout': 
      alert(title);
      break;
    case 'exercise': 
      alert(title);
      break;
  }
  let backAction = NavigationActions.back()
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(backAction)
  return;
} 
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into using redux?  In react it can get complicated if you have to pass data back up the tree.  If you look into redux its a central state store for all of your top level components (screens) in redux a top level component is called a container and it maps the state in the redux store to the props of the container, you can then pass this down to child components.  I think this is what you will need without having to re-engineer a solved problem :)

Comment: i have heard about it, and was going to look at it after my presentation, however i was looking for a short term fix for a project @Alex